# Basis consisting of vectors with non-negative entries only

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For a given linear space $X\subseteq{\bf R}^n$ of dimension $k$, can we always find a basis $b_0,\dots,b_{k-1}\in X$ consisting of vectors with non-negative entries?  If no, what is the smallest $\ell$ such that we find $b_0,\dots,b_{\ell-1}\in X$ with non-negative entries which span $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the subspace $X$ defined by $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0$. It doesn't contain any nonzero vectors with only nonnegative entries, so you can't even find a partial basis satisfying this condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  Unfortunately I asked the wrong question, I just realized, I don't want vectors which span $X$ but which span just the vectors in $X$ with non-negative entries.  I'll put that up as a new question.